# CDocument::SetPathName behaves differently in WinXp and Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows-7, mfc, windows-xp

When I called `CDocument::SetPathName` with 'eererr.hpr' in Windows XP it updates the member variable `m_strPathName` with value `'C:\Program Files\ICEHost\Projects\eererr.hpr'`

When I executed the same method in Windows 7 it updated `m_strPathName` with `'C:\Program Files\ICEHost\eererr.hpr'` `Projects` directory is missing in this path

What is the reason for this difference in WinXp and Windows 7?
Based on what information does `CDocument::SetPathName` updates `m_strPathName`?
How can make the behavior same?

Comment: Having a document inside `C:\Program Files\ ` is a bad sign and _will_ cause issues on Windows 7. Please fix this first, and then check if there is still an issue when you save your documents to `My Documents`.

Comment: @MSalters: I am having the same problem when I tried to save 'C:\ICE Products\ICeHost' folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SetPathName()` calls `GetFullPathName()` which "merges the name of the current drive and directory with a specified file name". So the difference is probably on how the current directory is obtained.

It is documented how CFileDialog selects a different initial directory on different OS (check `lpstrInitialDir` in the following 
[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). Maybe it has to do with that.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to override the AddToRecentFileList function.  The Add method is now implemented differently with Win7.  Check out this link

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/vcgeneral/thread/3fcb5f77-3c62-4d62-b01c-89a121ea835f